# WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException when using wait for async call in webjob

Tags: azure, asynchronous, queue, wait

I am using webjob in azure web site to deal with a heavy process which consumes high memory usage. The process does lots of web calls back-end, so it was designed as async. I want the webjob only deals with one request per instance. I've set the option Queues.BatchSize = 1 to disable parallel in webjob. However, when I use await to call the async method, the next message is still picked up right away from queue, as the await doesn't really block current thread, which is good for UI app, but not for my case.

So I tried to use wait to block current thread, until all the back-end process is done. However, An exception was thrown after the process is done. it seems like there is a problem for webjob to delete the queue after wait.

I attached the simplified test code and the exceptions.
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for the help!

namespace ProcessWebJob
{

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("testQueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
    {
        try
        {
            testAsync ts = new testAsync();
            var task = Task.Run(async () => { await ts.test(); });
            task.Wait();
        }catch(Exception e){
           Trace.TraceInformation("error on processing the queue message" + e.InnerException);
        } 

    }
}

public class testAsync {
   public async Task<int> test()  
   {
        await Task.Delay(10000); //10 seconds delay
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.<DeleteBlobImpl>b__29(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Protocols.PersistentQueueWriter`1.<DeleteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.CompositeFunctionInstanceLogger.<DeleteLogFunctionStartedAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.<TryExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueTriggerExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.d__11.MoveNext()
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[10/07/2015 17:57:14 > 278796: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

Comment: I am having the same thing right now and I would like to know if you fixed it?